# ping6 echo requests from container get lost partially

Tags: linux, networking, ipv6, systemd, lxc

Thanks to [kasperd's response on "ipv6 ping host got destination host unreachable until run tcpdump"](https://superuser.com/a/821596/743920) I learned about tcpdump putting the listened on interface into promiscous mode. When tcpdump'ing I always get duplicate replies – *if* I get a reply.

I have two servers (one virtual at a provider, one physical in a different data center), both are configured using IPv4 and IPv6. I can ping both servers on both protocols without any problems. But on my virtual server I have some containers (systemd-nspawn, but anything should also apply to Linux Containers (LXC)) which are networked using a bridge device br0 which bridges my physical interface and all container interfaces (shortened list):

```
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
br0     8000.0af08597bb89   no      ens3
                            vb-blog
[…]
                            vb-ttrss-alt
                            vb-web-proxy
```

systemd-nspawn uses systemd-networkd to configure network interfaces, routing and firewall. With IPv4 everything works fine in and out of the container. But with IPv6 I experience major package … loss(?). My observations so far:

- tcpdump'ing in the container is boring, all packets leave the interfaces
- tcpdump'ing on the veth interface bridged to br0 shows all the packets arriving

```
[root@persephone: ~]# tcpdump -e -n -i vb-ttrss-alt icmp6 and host 2a01:4f8:192:8370::2
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on vb-ttrss-alt, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
13:26:32.145734 ea:eb:e8:a1:43:37 > 0a:f0:85:97:bb:89, ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 118: 2a03:4000:59:b32:e8eb:e8ff:fea1:4337 > 2a01:4f8:192:8370::2: ICMP6, echo request, id 37732, seq 1, length 64
13:26:32.145783 0a:f0:85:97:bb:89 > 00:00:5e:00:02:02, ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 118: 2a03:4000:59:b32::1 > 2a01:4f8:192:8370::2: ICMP6, echo request, id 37732, seq 1, length 64
13:26:32.148557 10:0e:7e:26:f1:c0 > ea:eb:e8:a1:43:37, ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 118: 2a01:4f8:192:8370::2 > 2a03:4000:59:b32:e8eb:e8ff:fea1:4337: ICMP6, echo reply, id 37732, seq 1, length 64
13:26:33.147017 ea:eb:e8:a1:43:37 > 00:00:5e:00:02:02, ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 118: 2a03:4000:59:b32:e8eb:e8ff:fea1:4337 > 2a01:4f8:192:8370::2: ICMP6, echo request, id 37732, seq 2, length 64
13:26:34.149101 ea:eb:e8:a1:43:37 > 00:00:5e:00:02:02, ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 118: 2a03:4000:59:b32:e8eb:e8ff:fea1:4337 > 2a01:4f8:192:8370::2: ICMP6, echo request, id 37732, seq 3, length 64
13:26:35.162442 ea:eb:e8:a1:43:37 > 00:00:5e:00:02:02, ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 118: 2a03:4000:59:b32:e8eb:e8ff:fea1:4337 > 2a01:4f8:192:8370::2: ICMP6, echo request, id 37732, seq 4, length 64
13:26:36.175835 ea:eb:e8:a1:43:37 > 00:00:5e:00:02:02, ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 118: 2a03:4000:59:b32:e8eb:e8ff:fea1:4337 > 2a01:4f8:192:8370::2: ICMP6, echo request, id 37732, seq 5, length 64
13:26:37.189173 ea:eb:e8:a1:43:37 > 00:00:5e:00:02:02, ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 118: 2a03:4000:59:b32:e8eb:e8ff:fea1:4337 > 2a01:4f8:192:8370::2: ICMP6, echo request, id 37732, seq 6, length 64
13:26:38.202496 ea:eb:e8:a1:43:37 > 00:00:5e:00:02:02, ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 118: 2a03:4000:59:b32:e8eb:e8ff:fea1:4337 > 2a01:4f8:192:8370::2: ICMP6, echo request, id 37732, seq 7, length 64
13:26:39.215765 ea:eb:e8:a1:43:37 > 00:00:5e:00:02:02, ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 118: 2a03:4000:59:b32:e8eb:e8ff:fea1:4337 > 2a01:4f8:192:8370::2: ICMP6, echo request, id 37732, seq 8, length 64
13:26:40.229177 ea:eb:e8:a1:43:37 > 00:00:5e:00:02:02, ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 118: 2a03:4000:59:b32:e8eb:e8ff:fea1:4337 > 2a01:4f8:192:8370::2: ICMP6, echo request, id 37732, seq 9, length 64
13:26:41.242498 ea:eb:e8:a1:43:37 > 00:00:5e:00:02:02, ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 118: 2a03:4000:59:b32:e8eb:e8ff:fea1:4337 > 2a01:4f8:192:8370::2: ICMP6, echo request, id 37732, seq 10, length 64
13:26:45.298400 ea:eb:e8:a1:43:37 > 0a:f0:85:97:bb:89, ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 118: 2a03:4000:59:b32:e8eb:e8ff:fea1:4337 > 2a01:4f8:192:8370::2: ICMP6, echo request, id 37732, seq 14, length 64
13:26:45.298430 0a:f0:85:97:bb:89 > 00:00:5e:00:02:02, ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 118: 2a03:4000:59:b32::1 > 2a01:4f8:192:8370::2: ICMP6, echo request, id 37732, seq 14, length 64
13:26:45.301201 10:0e:7e:26:f1:c0 > ea:eb:e8:a1:43:37, ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 118: 2a01:4f8:192:8370::2 > 2a03:4000:59:b32:e8eb:e8ff:fea1:4337: ICMP6, echo reply, id 37732, seq 14, length 64
13:26:46.299646 ea:eb:e8:a1:43:37 > 00:00:5e:00:02:02, ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 118: 2a03:4000:59:b32:e8eb:e8ff:fea1:4337 > 2a01:4f8:192:8370::2: ICMP6, echo request, id 37732, seq 15, length 64
13:26:47.325802 ea:eb:e8:a1:43:37 > 00:00:5e:00:02:02, ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 118: 2a03:4000:59:b32:e8eb:e8ff:fea1:4337 > 2a01:4f8:192:8370::2: ICMP6, echo request, id 37732, seq 16, length 64
13:26:48.335803 ea:eb:e8:a1:43:37 > 00:00:5e:00:02:02, ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 118: 2a03:4000:59:b32:e8eb:e8ff:fea1:4337 > 2a01:4f8:192:8370::2: ICMP6, echo request, id 37732, seq 17, length 64
13:26:49.349148 ea:eb:e8:a1:43:37 > 00:00:5e:00:02:02, ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 118: 2a03:4000:59:b32:e8eb:e8ff:fea1:4337 > 2a01:4f8:192:8370::2: ICMP6, echo request, id 37732, seq 18, length 64
13:26:50.362468 ea:eb:e8:a1:43:37 > 00:00:5e:00:02:02, ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 118: 2a03:4000:59:b32:e8eb:e8ff:fea1:4337 > 2a01:4f8:192:8370::2: ICMP6, echo request, id 37732, seq 19, length 64
13:26:51.375801 ea:eb:e8:a1:43:37 > 00:00:5e:00:02:02, ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 118: 2a03:4000:59:b32:e8eb:e8ff:fea1:4337 > 2a01:4f8:192:8370::2: ICMP6, echo request, id 37732, seq 20, length 64
13:26:52.389144 ea:eb:e8:a1:43:37 > 00:00:5e:00:02:02, ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 118: 2a03:4000:59:b32:e8eb:e8ff:fea1:4337 > 2a01:4f8:192:8370::2: ICMP6, echo request, id 37732, seq 21, length 64
13:26:53.402445 ea:eb:e8:a1:43:37 > 00:00:5e:00:02:02, ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 118: 2a03:4000:59:b32:e8eb:e8ff:fea1:4337 > 2a01:4f8:192:8370::2: ICMP6, echo request, id 37732, seq 22, length 64
13:26:57.455790 ea:eb:e8:a1:43:37 > 0a:f0:85:97:bb:89, ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 118: 2a03:4000:59:b32:e8eb:e8ff:fea1:4337 > 2a01:4f8:192:8370::2: ICMP6, echo request, id 37732, seq 26, length 64
13:26:57.455842 0a:f0:85:97:bb:89 > 00:00:5e:00:02:02, ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 118: 2a03:4000:59:b32::1 > 2a01:4f8:192:8370::2: ICMP6, echo request, id 37732, seq 26, length 64
13:26:57.458657 10:0e:7e:26:f1:c0 > ea:eb:e8:a1:43:37, ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 118: 2a01:4f8:192:8370::2 > 2a03:4000:59:b32:e8eb:e8ff:fea1:4337: ICMP6, echo reply, id 37732, seq 26, length 64
13:26:58.457228 ea:eb:e8:a1:43:37 > 00:00:5e:00:02:02, ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 118: 2a03:4000:59:b32:e8eb:e8ff:fea1:4337 > 2a01:4f8:192:8370::2: ICMP6, echo request, id 37732, seq 27, length 64
```

- Before receiving an echo reply, there's a few seconds delay.
- The interval for succesfull pings varies between 12 seconds and a lot more. It seems to be dependent on me doing stuff in one of the connected sessions. When idling, it's between 12 and 13 seconds.
- tcpdump'ing on br0 is mostly the same.
- Without `-p` I get DUPs in the container, shown as follows in tcpdump:

```
13:30:09.885327 10:0e:7e:26:f1:c0 > ea:eb:e8:a1:43:37, ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 118: 2a01:4f8:192:8370::2 > 2a03:4000:59:b32:e8eb:e8ff:fea1:4337: ICMP6, echo reply, id 37732, seq 216, length 64
13:30:09.885343 0a:f0:85:97:bb:89 > ea:eb:e8:a1:43:37, ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 118: 2a01:4f8:192:8370::2 > 2a03:4000:59:b32:e8eb:e8ff:fea1:4337: ICMP6, echo reply, id 37732, seq 216, length 64
```

- With `-p` the DUPs dissappear.
- On the destination machine only some packets arrive:

```
root@neptun3 ~ # tcpdump -e -n -i enp2s0 icmp6 and net 2a03:4000:59:b32::/64
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on enp2s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
13:34:49.698515 0c:86:10:ed:37:1a > 44:8a:5b:5d:cf:11, ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 118: 2a03:4000:59:b32::1 > 2a01:4f8:192:8370::2: ICMP6, echo request, seq 8, length 64
13:34:49.698591 44:8a:5b:5d:cf:11 > 0c:86:10:ed:37:1a, ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 118: 2a01:4f8:192:8370::2 > 2a03:4000:59:b32::1: ICMP6, echo reply, seq 8, length 64
13:35:02.871916 0c:86:10:ed:37:1a > 44:8a:5b:5d:cf:11, ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 118: 2a03:4000:59:b32::1 > 2a01:4f8:192:8370::2: ICMP6, echo request, seq 21, length 64
13:35:02.871978 44:8a:5b:5d:cf:11 > 0c:86:10:ed:37:1a, ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 118: 2a01:4f8:192:8370::2 > 2a03:4000:59:b32::1: ICMP6, echo reply, seq 21, length 64
13:35:16.045152 0c:86:10:ed:37:1a > 44:8a:5b:5d:cf:11, ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 118: 2a03:4000:59:b32::1 > 2a01:4f8:192:8370::2: ICMP6, echo request, seq 34, length 64
13:35:16.045221 44:8a:5b:5d:cf:11 > 0c:86:10:ed:37:1a, ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 118: 2a01:4f8:192:8370::2 > 2a03:4000:59:b32::1: ICMP6, echo reply, seq 34, length 64
```

My systemd.network file on the container host for the bridge network is

```
[Match]
Name=br0

[Network]
Description=uplink interface
Address=202.61.199.186/22
Gateway=202.61.196.1
DNS=9.9.9.9
DNS=149.112.112.112

Address=2a03:4000:59:b32::1/64
Gateway=fe80::1
#IPv6AcceptRA=yes
DNS=2620:fe::fe
DNS=2620:fe::9

DHCPServer=yes
IPMasquerade=both
LLDP=yes
EmitLLDP=customer-bridge
IPv6SendRA=yes
DHCPPrefixDelegation=yes

[IPv6Prefix]
Prefix=2a03:4000:59:b32::/64

[DHCPServer]
ServerAddress=192.168.104.1/24
EmitDNS=yes
DNS=9.9.9.9 149.112.112.112
EmitRouter=yes
EmitTimezone=Europe/Berlin
```

The host side for the veth interface:

```
# SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT-0
#
# This config file is installed as part of systemd.
# It may be freely copied and edited (following the MIT No Attribution license).
#
# To make local modifications, one of the following methods may be used:
# 1. add a drop-in file that extends this file by creating the
#    /etc/systemd/network/99-default.link.d/ directory and creating a
#    new .conf file there.
# 2. copy this file into /etc/systemd/network or one of the other paths checked
#    by systemd-udevd and edit it there.
# This file should not be edited in place, because it'll be overwritten on upgrades.

[Match]
OriginalName=*

[Link]
NamePolicy=keep kernel database onboard slot path
AlternativeNamesPolicy=database onboard slot path
MACAddressPolicy=persistent
```

The container side

```
#  SPDX-License-Identifier: LGPL-2.1-or-later
#
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.

# This network file matches the container-side of the virtual Ethernet link
# created by systemd-nspawn's --network-veth switch. See systemd-nspawn(1) for
# details.

[Match]
Virtualization=container
Name=host0

[Network]
DHCP=yes
LinkLocalAddressing=yes
LLDP=yes
EmitLLDP=customer-bridge

[DHCP]
UseTimezone=yes
```

My best guesses are:

- It's not a firewall issue as some packets still make the whole roundtrip.
- It might be some case of MAC address mismatch mis-routing some packets.
- I did something wrong very early and don't recognize it anymore. FWIW it's my first and a half take at understanding IPv6. I recently moved this setup from another virtual server to this one, where it worked before. Or at least I didn't notice it not working.
- Pure evil to drive me insane!

Any hints?

Comment: Your tcpdump doesn't capture any multicast traffic (actually nor unicast) used for link local connectivity (it's the replacement for IPv4's ARP). This would be useful. Maybe something like `or (multicast and not broadcast) or net fe80::/10` to add, with quotes around to protect from the shell? Then using `-i any` would give in one capture all the involved interfaces (so there will be duplicates all the time with this mode). Also, nothing strange with `ip -6 neigh` or `ip -6 monitor neigh`?